# Read context.xml file from other project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-3

Can I read the context.xml file from different java projects?

Project A has context.xml file

Project B does not have context file, but I have to read the context file from project A and do certain things.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: how are project A and B related? can they be modules of a the same parent/group project? can you explain a bit further the use case for the file within the context of Project B?

Answer (score 0):

Project A needs to add Project B as dependency in order to use functions inside project B.

My issue was that Project A had dependency in Project B and in Project B I had to call method from project A. This way I had to add Project A as dependency of Project B. But how project A already had dependency in project B, this way it caused a cycle dependency error.